# Dajngo sets CSRF cookie when I turn the CsrfViewMiddleware off. And does not set CSRF cookie when expected

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman, csrf

I am having strange behaviour regarding the setting of a CSRF cookie by Django in Postman & Chrome and with different settings:

Situation 1:

I set `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in my `MIDDLEWARE` settings.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I do a POST call with Postman to a REST endpoint:

```
class BlogCreateView(APIView):
    
    http_method_names = ['post']
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return {
            'request': self.request,
            'kwargs': kwargs,
        }

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        """
        POST a new object
        """
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        serializer = self.serializer(data=request.data, context=context)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        new_instance = serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The CSRF cookie is not set. I don't set a csrf value in the header of the request either. But the server accepts it. This should not happen right?

Situation 2:

When i simply go to `http://localhost:8000/blogs/create` in my Chrome browser. This makes a `GET` request to the same endpoint. The response is `"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."` which is expected. But the cookie IS set in the browser.

Situation 3:
I turn off `CsrfViewMiddleware`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

And I do a POST call to my Graphene endpoint with Postman:

```
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView
urlpatterns = [
    path('graphql', GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True)),
]
```

And now the cookie is set in Postman! This combination of situations makes no sense to me. Help would be much appreciated.

My goal is to have csrf protection working for production eventually. But I would like to test it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Try insert `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` **after** `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware`.

Like this:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: I tried. The same still happens. Thanks for the suggestion. I updated it in the code in my question.